# Playwright wait for base URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, playwright

I'm developing a simple test with Playwright, and read that you can set on the global configuration file the baseURL for your tests. So I did as stated on the documentation:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
  }
};
export default config;
```

Thing is that the actual test will fail when using the syntax below because it seems baseURL is not loaded yet:

```
it('Should populate every input in the form', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.fill("some='selector'", "some value") //error because baseURL is not loaded yet
});
```

If I add a `await page.goto("/")` before the line causing error it works fine. But it makes sense to me that if we are setting a base URL page should be ready when inside the test. How do I wait for the page to have its base URL loaded, without having to `goto()` someplace just so that page is loaded?

Comment: The baseURL feature does currently not navigate automatically to your baseURL. You need to do that either manually in each test, have a beforeEach or do it via a custom fixture. See here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-before-each